# How to use zxing barcode reader to read multiple barcodes in one image

Tags: android, cordova, image-processing, zxing

I have a given string e.g. 'start123' and I want to scan over a picture that shows three different QR-codes. One of the code has the information 'start123' inside itself and the other two have different strings encoded.

I would like to scan over the complete picture and somehow mark the QR-code (for example with a red square around) that contains my given string.

I already took a close look at Zxing's barcode library and saw a function called 'GenericMultipleBarcodeReader' but I am using PhoneGap and there is only the .scan() function available (or atleast I didn't found any other).

Can I realize what is depicted above without coding too much on my own, as I am not an expert in image processing...

Hope somebody can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't read multiple codes at once and you get the code position within the image you can delete every code from the image and read again.

If you don't get the position from your library you can create multiple small subimages or use regions of interest to evaluate. Then add every detected code to your collection.

Comment: ok, sounds logical. But how to implement all that? I sounds like it requires certain skill in image processing.
Normally the functionality is already there, I am just looking for the right way to use it inside PhoneGap.

Comment: sry I don't know PhoneGap. Find out how to get image processing functionality into PhoneGap. The image processing knowledge required is very basic so you should be fine. Google should help. This is to broad for this platform. Start with finding someone who can tell you how to get image processing done in phone gap. then come back here.

Comment: PhoneGap is just a framework that allows you to use e.g. javascript and html code in an android app.
I looked at the incredible amount of code in ZXing and I have no idea how to modify something there to fit my needs... I can hardly imagine someone write all this codes if you can only use super simple functions like .scan() in the end.
I guess I just don't understand how to use this multiple scan function which is already there...